# Necessary/Sufficient conditions eigenvalues random matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, random-matrices

I am working on the computational analysis of the eigenvalue spectra of real symmetric random matrices. At the moment my approach is fully empirical but I would like to develop a rough model of the eigenvalue spectrum as a function of matrix size (for NxN matrices).

In particular, I am interested in setting a probability upper bound (as close as possible to the l.u.b.) for the largest eigenvalue falling within lambda -> lambda + delta_lambda.

The entries of such matrices are i.i.d. random variables (say gaussian).

My first idea was to look at the pdf (with N as a parameter) for Tr(matrix). In fact we know that the trace being larger than N*(*lambda*) is a sufficient condition for the largest eigenvalue being larger than *lambda*, by Pidgeon-hole principle. However, the fact that such condition is not necessary means we are underestimating the probability upper bound.

Are there alternative conditions for the largest eigenvalue value whose characteristic pdf is reasonably easy to obtain and at the same gives a good approximation - does not need to be exact - of the overall probability least upper bound?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If your random real, symmetric matrices have Gaussian measure, then your problem is the Gaussian Orthogonal Ensemble (GOE). The largest eigenvalue will follow a Tracy-Widom distibution as $N\rightarrow\infty$ and the marginal distribution for an eigenvalue (the "bulk" distribution) will follow a semicircle law as  $N\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I read about that prior to posting this question but my interest at the moment is in fact oriented toward finite N effects and how the associated pdf for the largest eigenvalue varies with different matrix sizes (as it tends to the T-W). My question is really about more or less strict conditions on the matrix entries, rather than particular cases for known ensambles. Sorry for not being clear in my original post.

Comment: I see what you're after. You can use the [Gershgorin circle theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem) to find the strict upper bound for a given matrix. Even better you could tridiagonalize, or use a [tridiagonal matrix model](https://www.math.washington.edu/~dumitriu/JMathPhys_43_5830.pdf), and then use Gersh.